# re-design circular dependency flaw

Tags: go, software-design, circular-dependency

I've a bunch of small services that share some common packages like `Logger`, `Configuration` and `Net`. And I wrote each package in separated project.
The issue is that my `Logger` needs package `Configuration` for set up. And my `Configuration` (**not** solely used by `Logger`) wants to write output log when necessary.

Therefore, I've circular dependency flaw `Logger`**-->**`Configuration`, `Configuration`**-->**`Logger`.

How can I redesign this code?

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to this came up at GopherCon this year where Edward Muller argued that having config structs increased coupling in your application.  The configuration package is just an extreme version of this.  He argued that instead the dependency should just take in the bits of the configuration that it actually needs rather than the whole struct (or package in this case).  You can see this part of his talk here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltqV6pDKZD8

Or a textual version here:

https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/idiomatic-go/#config-structs

The essence of his solution would be to have you main do something like:

```
logSetting1 := configuration.GetLogSetting1()
logSetting2 := configuration.GetLogSetting2()
logger.SetSettings(logSetting1, logSetting2)
```

You will probably also have a "what gets created first" problem if your logger needs some settings from the config in order to initialize itself. I avoid this by creating a logger with sensible defaults, creating the configuration object using the default logger then adjusting the logger based on the loaded configuration.  This means that you temporally have a logger that isn't configured correctly but the *only* thing you do with it is use it for logging the loading of the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly your `Configuration` package looks like, but I don't think the `Logger` should have a dependency to the `Configuration` package.

In the end you probably want to configure the logger somehow. IMO this configuration shouldn't be more than a struct. So one solution might be:

1. put the logger dependent configuration into on struct inside the logger package
2. let the configuration package generate the logger config struct
3. initialize the logger either in the configuration package or in some upper level package

Answer (score 0):

Usually that problem get solved by creating third module that has dependencies for other two:
[image]

Comment: Probably some people just envious of my superior graphic skills

Comment: That is because while the practise is common, it is not idomatic and widely critisized in golang community. And would you please try to elaborate to me how would you write the **common dependecies**? It is even too abstract to be an answer.

Comment: Is there a source claiming that method not being idiomatic? I tried to google it and top article http://mantish.com/post/dealing-with-import-cycle-go/ advise for creating third package. Also read through google talks, there were no bashing of that method.
Whats wrong with abstract answer? Its useful to be abstract when we trying to help not one but many users with similar problems.

Comment: every time I try this IRL I just end up with a third module that is dependent in a circular relationship with the other two